# Inherit bootstrap class with SASS in node

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I want to add [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) CSS to my own sub-elements by using SASS [inheritance](http://sass-lang.com/guide):

```
nav > a {
  @extend: .nav-item;
  @extend: .nav-link;
}
```

I use Node with [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) for bundling. And I've installed the [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#d-npm--nodejs) but I can't seem to get the `@import 'bootstrap'` to work. All I get is `File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap`. The sass part of the webpack code is:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
  ....,
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass'),
  }],
```

I guess this must be something trivial that I've missed. It's not entirely surprising that SASS doesn't have access to the library but I haven't found any good hints on how to provide the library directly to SASS.

Comment: This question is not related to [tag:css].

Comment: I think, your `@extend` syntax is wrong. check https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/ for more details.

Comment: @DeepakYadav thought it may be problematic. Updated to an alternative structure, do you think this will work? I would be happy though if I got that far...

Answer (score 1):

I literally have no what you have done so far for setup and other things. In simple english, if you are using SASS files downloaded from bootstrap's official website, you can use their mixins, variables and extend code in your own code file. Though it needs proper project setup for files and import them in a proper way.

In the shared code, your syntax for `@extend` appears to be wrong. I have shown a dummy code snippet for demo purpose.

```
// code already written inside Bootstrap source file.
.nav-item {
  background:red;
}
.nav-link {
  color: #fff;
}

// your code 
.nav > a {
  @extend .nav-item;
  @extend .nav-link;
}
```

You can use http://www.sassmeister.com/website for trial and error.

This is what it looks like, when compiled.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have a node project with webpack for building. The main question is that I want to be able to call @import from the scss and extend the bootstrap with my own classes/elements. I have currently loaded bootstrap from a cdn but this won't work for importing which is why I tried the npm bootstrap-sass module.

Comment: @MaxGordon yes, **CDN** reference won't do. you need to download the whole SASS zip and extract it to your source code folder and `@import` the `bootstrap.scss` file from that folder inside your `main.scss` file

Comment: I was hoping that the bootstrap-sass library could somehow be magically loaded into webpack, allowing a simple `@import bootstrap` in the scss without the entire path